# How to create a random JS object?

Tags: javascript, object, random

I would like to know if there is a way of creating a JavaScript object which is randomized. Understand randomized as such: the resulting object has a random set of properties, every of which has a random name. The problem boils down to two:

1) Is it possible to have an object created at runtime, without earlier specifying the amount of properties?

2) Is it possible to randomize names of the object's properties?

I'm looking for an explanation/solution, not only a no/yes answer.

Comment: Yes and Yes, make a function that returns a random string, loop that a random number of times calling `obj[rand_string]=some_other_random_value`

Comment: Answer to question 1: Sure, why wouldn't it be? 2: Yes, because you can add properties on the fly, you can add random values, assigned to random properties. You really ought to show some effort, though. Show some code, what have you tried? Have you googled some info on this matter? Show that you've put in some effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very crude way to do it, can't think of any use case for it:

```
function randomObject(){
    var ret = {};
    var propertyCount= Math.random() * 10;
    for (var x = 0; x < propertyCount; x++ ){
        ret[Math.random()] = Math.random(); 
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Ok, this answer is correct. Obvious as it looks questions if asking the question was necessary. Well... no. But I tried to achieve the effect with the curly brackets notation, hence the question. Thank you for your answer anyway - I changed the approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how it could be useful, but yes, it's possible.

```
var MAX_PROPERTIES = 50;
var ALLOWED_CHARACTERS_IN_KEY = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_";
var MAX_KEY_LENGTH = 30;

var object = {};
var propertiesCount = Math.round(Math.random() * MAX_PROPERTIES);
for(var i = 0 ; i < propertiesCount ; i++) {
    var keyLength = Math.round(Math.random() * MAX_KEY_LENGTH);
    var randKey = "";
    for(var j = 0 ; j < keyLength ; j++) {
        randKey += ALLOWED_CHARACTERS_IN_KEY[Math.floor(Math.random() * ALLOWED_CHARACTERS_IN_KEY.length)];
    }

    var randValue = Math.random();
    object[randKey] = randValue;
}
```

Note that some keys could begin with a number, which is not callable with the dot notation.

Example :

```
{
    "NmkQZWeW9_ojadERwK74HXYj43Lw":0.3039316821878978,
    "PZiFauEC6H":0.04273172815465165,
    "2m7cMrwRPoxpa8LvmpAaJ":0.7010494474513925,
    "D":0.4552683870622114,
    "HQhIxPxO8tsdocRuGJpnhB7k2PjD":0.18360190519964337,
    "rVwM8":0.8681098855694265,
    "3Vf5HGYDOmUli3":0.527829742115212,
    "fQ4ryGL2cxhJeRd":0.10353706566292953,
    "D_DQqODu_":0.1272988336424956,
    "8UY0a7":0.17057184875868092,
    "8i1uVtPwzl0KRA8iYZ4uKcPKF":0.9554370948377217,
    "TTi":0.038665872114993616,
    "YofUj9RrK7foQrl":0.5835241172217945,
    "sb3SzEB_":0.17136910050721899,
    "801FopHCCML4ozrfmjak":0.10999126507324442,
    "D8":0.05981337403919851,
    "oL8ZZvrAG":0.36816486041399255,
    "hfXxJ0sNp42y2HYEDXLBYgZ6mV":0.13977757384990708,
    "2xx4AJrQswA5TIcXr":0.8610074761855161,
    "68RNcKQmgnh_qTG":0.5234909406332302,
    "wJsV8BRo1cT2MtXDuh":0.4497261910215308,
    "6yFr4E81bvXK":0.5996413679577888,
    "Px2bjBvFSBu":0.017922504534248707,
    "yazK1KQbmUhE4Ul1rZX5hf0yulX_JK":0.7105144243046027,
    "cXmdnvmP":0.028121925940253756,
    "R_fDjw9yBejk3":0.699514797889162,
    "z":0.34347612922580006,
    "2kTX6Q2tzbCo3":0.678962211994213
}
```

Comment: Or long_random_int.toString(36) for random 0-9A-Za-z without a dictionary

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, but without caps and with a (relatively) uniform length.